# discord.py Passing context and self to function in class

Tags: python, discord.py, python-3.9

### I am trying to create a bot, which uses discord.py's VoiceClient.

The problem is, when you name a variable in a function it doesn't get passed on to the other functions. So the variable `voicebot` doesn't get passed on to the other functions (which are for making the bot leave or talk)

```
intents = discord.Intents.all()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=commands.when_mentioned_or("~"),intents=intents, owner_id=587573816360960022)

...Other functions...

@bot.command(name='join', help='Joins the voice channel you are in')
async def JoinVoiceofAuthor(ctx):
   vchannel = ctx.message.author.voice
   if vchannel != None:
       if "voicebot" not in globals():
           global voicebot
           voicebot = await vchannel.channel.connect()
       else:
           if voicebot.is_connected():
                   return
           if vchannel != None:
               voicebot = await vchannel.channel.connect()
       await ctx.send('Joining you, '+str(ctx.message.author.mention)+', in voice channel "'+str(vchannel.channel)+'"')
   else:
       await ctx.send('Sorry,'+str(ctx.message.author.mention)+', you are not in a voice channel')

...Other functions...
```

I tried making `voicebot` a global variable, but found out, that you can't change global varibales from a function.
So my next idea was to make the bot a class:

```
class TheBot(commands.Bot):
    def __init__(self):
        intents = discord.Intents.all()

        super().__init__(intents=intents, command_prefix='~',  owner_id=587573816360960022)
        members = inspect.getmembers(self)
        for name, member in members:
            if isinstance(member, commands.Command):
                if member.parent is None:
                    self.add_command(member)

...Other functions...

    @commands.command(name='join', help='Joins the voice channel you are in')
    async def JoinVoiceofAuthor(self, ctx):
        vchannel = ctx.message.author.voice
        if vchannel != None:
            if "voicebot" not in globals():
                self.voicebot = await vchannel.channel.connect()
            else:
                if self.voicebot.is_connected():
                        return
                if vchannel != None:
                    self.voicebot = await vchannel.channel.connect()
            await ctx.send('Joining you, '+str(ctx.message.author.mention)+', in voice channel "'+str(vchannel.channel)+'"')
        else:
            await ctx.send('Sorry,'+str(ctx.message.author.mention)+', you are not in a voice channel')

...Other functions...
```

But that also didn't work, because the **Context** was also passed on to `self` and not to `ctx`

Does someone have a solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Parasol Kirby said, you need to use the `global` keyword. To adapt this to your case we need to make some changes.

To make the `voicebot` variable global just add `global voicebot` at the top of the command. That way you can use this variable from every function.

Then to check if the bot is already connected to a voice channel, we do not need to use the `voicebot` variable. You can create a function that returns `True` if the bot is in a voice channel like this:

```py
def is_connected(ctx):
    voice_client = discord.utils.get(ctx.bot.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
    return voice_client and voice_client.is_connected()
```

Now to check if the bot is not connected to a voice channel from within the command, just use the `is_connected` function and "pass in" the context.

```py
if not is_connected(ctx):
```

So the full code looks like this:

```py
def is_connected(ctx):
    voice_client = discord.utils.get(ctx.bot.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
    return voice_client and voice_client.is_connected()

@bot.command(name='join', help='Joins the voice channel you are in')
async def JoinVoiceofAuthor(ctx):
    global voicebot

    vchannel = ctx.message.author.voice
    if vchannel != None:
        if not is_connected(ctx):
            voicebot = await vchannel.channel.connect()
            await ctx.send('Joining you, '+str(ctx.message.author.mention)+', in voice channel "'+str(vchannel.channel)+'"')
```

Comment: Thanks! I thought there may be a more beautiful way to do it, but I think I am going to stick with this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change a global variable from a function, you must use the global keyword from inside the function:

```py
x = 50
def add_to_x(num):
    global x
    x += num

print(x)
add_to_x(10)
print(x)


#The Output is this:
50
60
```

And an implementation in discord.py would be:

```py
x = 50
@bot.command()
async def add_to_x(ctx,amount):
    global x
    print(x)
    x += int(amount)
    print(x)
```